# iOS animations stop working until camera is launched

Tags: ios

I have a view in my app that displays files and allows the user to reorder them and there is a navigation pane that animates in and out of view. Also while reordering files there is an animation as they slide into place. Touching one of the files loads the details in a modal view.

My problem occurs when loading a modal. They will work for awhile, but then one will animate up and when its dismissed it just snaps off screen without an animation and from that point forward no animations run, everything just goes to its final position (my animations and iOS modals and UINavigationController pops and pushs, even rotation just snaps to the new rotation)

My app allows for loading up the default camera for taking pictures to add to the file list and when the camera loads it animates up and after it closes all animations work again for awhile until a modal messes it up again. I've been on SO looking for a solution and I've found some similar things, but I haven't found anything that fixes the problem.

- These modals are loaded using presentModalView and the information shown in them is static

**Edit:**
I don't think the code is all to helpful, I'm using a story board so I'm calling the segue and then preparing the segue with the following.

```
PhotoVC* destinationVC = (PhotoVC*) segue.destinationViewController;
destinationVC.displayImage = m_sendImage;
```

I have nothing running in the willAppear of either view. None of my animations are active when the modal is presented.

Comment: Without providing code, it's possible, but certainly unlikely that someone will have a solution.

Comment: You need to show the code for presenting and dismissing your modal view controllers.

Comment: Not 100% sure of what exactly you're doing but I can imagine that as modal views goes on/off screen, the animations can be frozen because of the way it works. Its like a before and after snapshot with the in between states gradually transitioned. I'm doubt the other animations will be allowed to play as the modal view transition happens because the view is being created or destroyed. Try a simple experiment.

Comment: I've added code, it's probably not going to help